# Count by group across multiple columns

Tags: r, count

My dataset looks like this:

```
Names       Sample   Init_QC  Run_QC
A             DN      PASS     PASS
A             DN      FAIL     PASS
A             RN      FAIL     FAIL
B             DN      PASS     FAIL
B             DN      PASS     PASS
B             RN      FAIL     PASS
C             DN      PASS     FAIL
C             DN      FAIL     FAIL
C             RN      PASS     PASS
```

I am looking to have things summarized by "Names" by counting number of occurrences of each category. Result would look like this:

```
Names   DN  RN   Init_QC$PASS  Init_QC$FAIL   Run_QC$PASS   Run_QC$FAIL
 A      2    1       1              2             2              1
 B      2    1       2              1             2              1
 C      2    1       1              2             1              2
```

I was hoping to use "table" or "count" from dplyr but without success

Would anyone have an easy way to do this ?
Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle I would do it this way. I have tried to shorten the code but failed:
The code should be self explained. First `count` and split the `df` by the desired columns and `pivot_wider`. Finally bring them all together:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
  count(Names, Sample) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Sample, values_from=n, names_glue = ) 

df2 <- df %>% 
  count(Names, Init_QC) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from= Init_QC, values_from = n, names_glue = "Init_QC${Init_QC}")

df3 <- df %>% 
  count(Names, Run_QC) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from= Run_QC, values_from = n, names_glue = "Run_QC${Run_QC}")

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2) %>% 
  left_join(df3)
```

```
  Names    DN    RN `Init_QC$FAIL` `Init_QC$PASS` `Run_QC$FAIL` `Run_QC$PASS`
  <chr> <int> <int>          <int>          <int>         <int>         <int>
1 A         2     1              2              1             1             2
2 B         2     1              1              2             1             2
3 C         2     1              1              2             2             1
```

Comment: I have a shorter code below

Answer (score 4):

In base R:

```
 aggregate(.~Names, df, table)

  Names Sample.DN Sample.RN Init_QC.FAIL Init_QC.PASS Run_QC.FAIL Run_QC.PASS
1     A         2         1            2            1           1           2
2     B         2         1            1            2           1           2
3     C         2         1            1            2           2           1
```

To make everything into columns, do:

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(.~Names, df, table))

  Names Sample.DN Sample.RN Init_QC.FAIL Init_QC.PASS Run_QC.FAIL Run_QC.PASS
1     A         2         1            2            1           1           2
2     B         2         1            1            2           1           2
3     C         2         1            1            2           2           1
```

Using `reshape2:`

```
reshape2::recast(df, Names~variable+value, fun.agg = length, id.var = 'Names')

  Names Sample_DN Sample_RN Init_QC_FAIL Init_QC_PASS Run_QC_FAIL Run_QC_PASS
1     A         2         1            2            1           1           2
2     B         2         1            1            2           1           2
3     C         2         1            1            2           2           1
```

In tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)  
df %>%
   pivot_longer(-Names) %>%
   count(Names, name, value) %>%
   pivot_wider(Names, names_from = c(name, value), values_from = n)

# A tibble: 3 x 7
  Names Init_QC_FAIL Init_QC_PASS Run_QC_FAIL Run_QC_PASS Sample_DN Sample_RN
  <chr>        <int>        <int>       <int>       <int>     <int>     <int>
1 A                2            1           1           2         2         1
2 B                1            2           1           2         2         1
3 C                1            2           2           1         2         1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tidyverse` way.

```r
x <- 'Names       Sample   Init_QC  Run_QC
A             DN      PASS     PASS
A             DN      FAIL     PASS
A             RN      FAIL     FAIL
B             DN      PASS     FAIL
B             DN      PASS     PASS
B             RN      FAIL     PASS
C             DN      PASS     FAIL
C             DN      FAIL     FAIL
C             RN      PASS     PASS'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

df1 %>%
  count(Names, Sample) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Sample, 
    values_from = n
  ) %>%
  left_join(
    df1 %>%
      select(-Sample) %>%
      pivot_longer(
        cols = ends_with("QC"),
        names_to = "QC",
        values_to = "value"
      ) %>%
      count(Names, QC, value) %>%
      pivot_wider(
        names_from = c("QC", "value"),
        values_from = n
      ),
    by = "Names"
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   Names    DN    RN Init_QC_FAIL Init_QC_PASS Run_QC_FAIL Run_QC_PASS
#>   <chr> <int> <int>        <int>        <int>       <int>       <int>
#> 1 A         2     1            2            1           1           2
#> 2 B         2     1            1            2           1           2
#> 3 C         2     1            1            2           2           1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit more complex than it should be, but it does the job:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(Names = unique(df$Names)) %>%
  bind_cols(table(df$Names, df$Sample), table(df$Names, df$Init_QC)) %>%
  rename(Init_FAIL = FAIL, Init_PASS = PASS) %>%
  bind_cols(table(df$Names, df$Run_QC)) %>%
  rename(Run_FAIL = FAIL, Run_PASS = PASS)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   Names    DN    RN Init_FAIL Init_PASS Run_FAIL Run_PASS
#>   <chr> <int> <int>     <int>     <int>    <int>    <int>
#> 1 A         2     1         2         1        1        2
#> 2 B         2     1         1         2        1        2
#> 3 C         2     1         1         2        2        1
```

Comment: Check the code I provided. Its quite straight forward

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# summary for each column
x <- names(df)
y <- rbindlist(lapply(setdiff(x, 'id'), \(i) df[, .(rows=.N), c('id', i)][, (i) := paste0(i, '_', get(i))])
               , F
               )

# long to wide
dcast(y, paste('id', '~', x[2]))
```